# Login depending on the value of spinner

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am creating an app in Flutter, home screen of which shows a spinner which contains its value as the people belonging to 6 different departments.
Now when a user comes to that screen he will choose the department he belongs and then type in the username and password, then the google firebase will authenticate that person and if all correct logs in otherwise not.
I want to know that depending on the value of that spinner how can I authenticate the user.

The layout of my homescreen is given below. [image: Homescreen[][1]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in a couple of different ways. The first one is using `cloud firestore` or `realtime database` (I am assuming you use one of this to store user data). In your `users` node or table add department field and store the department of each user. Then authenticate the user using `firebase auth` and if the authentication is successful get the users user id and use it to find the uses data in the database. Then check whether the users department selection matches with the department field in the database. If it does direct the user to his/her homepage. Otherwise show an error message.

```
                     FirebaseAuth.instance
                        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                            email: emailInputController.text,
                            password: pwdInputController.text)
                            .catchError((error) => {
                              Print(error.code)
                            })
                        .then((currentUser) => Firestore.instance
                            .collection("users")
                            .document(currentUser.user.uid)
                            .get()
                            .then(
                              (doc) => {
                                 if(doc['role'] == roleChoice){
                                    //Navigate to home
                                 }
                                 else{
                                    /show error
                                 }
                               }
                            );
                    } on AuthException catch (error) {

                      Print(error.code);
                      return error;
                    }
```

The other way is using defining roles via backend script. You can find how to do that [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#defining_roles_via_backend_script).

Comment: thanks for telling me the correct method, till now I was following the approach of registering the user based upon their email id and phone number and on login page giving them choice to which dept they belongs. Now I can give them this choice at the register screen only. **Tell me one more thing if I give them choice at the registration screen only it may be possible that they intentionally choose other dept to look into that dept. which I don't want to happen**

Comment: I think you need to have an admin that specifies which user belongs to which department. If you give the choice to the user they will choose whatever department they want to and you can not control that. And I think you need to rethink how the flow of the app is going to be. But if this answered your current question please mark it as correct